# What does `with pkgs.lib; head [ 1 2 3]` mean?

Tags: nix, nixos

In an old version of https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/#sec-package-management, it said

> ```
> with pkgs.lib; head [ 1 2 3]
> ```
>
> Add all attributes from the given set to the scope (evaluates to  1 )

What does the line of code mean?

Does `head [ 1 2 3]` mean extracting the first element from the list, and therefore the whole line "evaluates to 1"?

What does `with pkgs.lib` mean?

Answer (score 1):

`with expr1; expr2` makes all attributes of `expr1` in scope for `expr2`. For example:

```hs
with { foo = 5; }; foo
```

Evaluates to `5`.

`head` is a an attribute [in `pkgs.lib`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/4ecab3273592f27479a583fb6d975d4aba3486fe/lib/default.nix#L67), which means that in the expression following `with pkgs.lib;`, `head` will automatically be in scope.

If you want to know what the whole expression evaluates to, you can try it in `nix repl`:

```bash
$ nix repl --file "<nixpkgs>"
nix-repl> with lib; lib.head [ 1 2 3 ]
```

`with` expressions are also [documented in the Nix manual in the Nix language section](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/language/constructs#with-expressions).